# how to set KeyboardAvoidingView keyboard vertical offset background color?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

i'm using   KeyboardAvoidingView with keyboardVerticalOffset={50}.
this offset made there is filled with white color. how can i change the color?
actually i want to make it transparent.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Would love to see an answer to this.